# Stacked bar chart using tibble in R

Tags: r, plot, tibble, stacked-chart

I have the following tibble `df`:

```
`Region`    `Product`    `Cost`
 <fct>       <fct>        <dbl>
 1 Japan     Laptop       1500
 2 Egypt     Printer      450
 ...
```

and I would like to create a stacked barplot with `Region` on the x-axis, and the each column being the sum of all the costs in that region broken down into `Product` categories (i.e. a stack of total costs per product for the given region.)

I have unsuccessfully tried the following:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = "Region", y = "Cost")) + geom_col(aes(fill = "Product"))
```

Could someone please help me out?
Thanks!

Comment: Remove the quotes from it. Try `ggplot(df, aes(x = Region, y = Cost)) + geom_col(aes(fill = Product))`

Comment: You can formalize your comment as an answer if you'd like and I'll select it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you pass variable names in quoted format as string, it considers that as value to plot. In `ggplot2` syntax to refer to a column you have to pass them as unquoted variables. So try :

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = Region, y = Cost)) + geom_col(aes(fill = Product))
```